# In specs2, conditionally executing subtests on result returned from function that may throw exceptions

Tags: scala, testing, bdd, specs2

In specs2, what is the proper way to express a pattern of subtests that only execute if its "parent" test returned a result without throwing an exception?

I have a function `maybeGiveMeAThing`, and it can either return a `Thing`, or throw exceptions.

A call looks like this:

`val thing: Thing = maybeGiveMeAThing("foo", "bar" "baz"`)

I want to test that with a certain set of inputs, that `maybeGiveMeAThing` successfully returns a Thing without throwing an exception, and using the Thing returned, do further tests to ensure that it is the correct `Thing` returned for the parameters given to `maybeGiveMeAThing`.

The way I have the tests currently set up, if the call to `maybeGiveMeAThing` throws an exception, the entire test suite gets aborted.  This would be the logic I prefer:

- If a `Thing` was returned successfully, proceed with a set of subtests that analyze the contents of thing
- If `maybeGiveMeAThing` threw an exception (any exception), skip the subtests that analyze thing, but continue with the rest of the tests

My existing test code looks roughly like:

```
// ...
"with good parameters" in {
  var thing: Thing = null   

  "return a Thing without throwing an exception" in {
    thing = maybeGiveMeAThing("some", "good", "parameters", "etc.")
  } should not(throwA[Exception])


  "the Thing returned should contain a proper Foo" in {
       thing.foo mustBe "bar"

  }
    //... etc ...
}

// ...

}
```

...although this feels like it's way off from the right way to do it.  What would be the proper way?
(I would like to avoid using `var`s if I can help it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use a condition as in @alexwriteshere answer:

```
"parent test" in {
  val thing: Option[Thing] = maybeGiveMeAThing("foo", "bar" "baz")

  thing match {
    case Some(thing) =>
      "child test 1" in ok
      "child test 2" in ok
    case None =>
      "skipped tests" in skipped
  }
}
```

However you need to add an `Example` in the `None` case so that the block of the `in` method has an acceptable type.

The big drawback with this approach though is that the specification is being executed while being defined. This means that:

- if there's an exception with the `maybeGiveMeAThing` then the whole specification will blow up
- if you choose to exclude the examples using the `thing`, you will still have it being built

Another option is to use a `Step` saying that any previous failure will skip all the next examples:

```
class MySpec extends mutable.Specification {
  "This is a test with a thing" >> {
    lazy val thing: Option[Thing] = maybeGiveMeAThing("foo", "bar" "baz")

    "the thing should be ok" >> {
      thing must beOk
    }

    step(stopOnFail = true)
    "other examples with thing" >> {
      "ex1" >> ok
      "ex2" >> ok
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple if/else with the child cases will do what you want. Or, you could make the "maybeGiveMeAThing" method return an option, and then match it.

```
"parent test" in {
      val thing: Option[Thing] = maybeGiveMeAThing("foo", "bar" "baz")

      thing match {
        case Some(thing) =>
          "child test 1" in {
            ...
          }

          "child test 2" in {
            ...
          }
        case None =>
          // don't run additional tests
      }
    }
```

If maybeGiveMeAThing *has* to return an exception, you could catch it and make the method return an Option.

Comment: When I tried structuring it this way, I got a compilation error (`could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[Product with Serializable]`, with the caret pointing at the `in` immediately following the `"parent test"`).  Any ideas?

Comment: But +1 for convincing me to wrap it in an Option.